# Run batch file on source code edit\save in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2012

What I'm trying to accomplish is have a custom batch or exe run every time I edit and save a source file in visual studio.  It doesn't have to run on every single file, I really only have 12 .cs files that I want to do this for.  It would be great to be able to kick off a new batch\exe with a parameter of the file that was just saved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012 you can make an add-in as follows which will catch the Save event and run your batch file

File > New Project

Choose Extensibility 
Choose Visual Studio Add-in

In Connect.cs:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, 
                         object addInInst, ref Array custom)
{
    _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
    _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

    if (_de == null)
    {
        _de = _applicationObject.Events.get_DocumentEvents(null);
    }
    //Handle document saved event
    if (_deSavedEvent == null)
    {
        _deSavedEvent = new _dispDocumentEvents_DocumentSavedEventHandler(
                                               DocumentEvents_DocumentSaved);
        _de.DocumentSaved += _deSavedEvent;
    }
}

private static DocumentEvents _de = null;
private static _dispDocumentEvents_DocumentSavedEventHandler _deSavedEvent =null;

private void DocumentEvents_DocumentSaved(EnvDTE.Document document)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Replace this with code to run .bat");
}
```

Code sample taken from http://www.grebulon.com/software/stripem.php

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the best was to do this would be to create a custom shortcut under the tools menu of VS, where it will then run.

> To add custom shortcut keys
>
> 1. On the Tools menu, select Options, open the Environment folder, and
>    choose Keyboard.
> 2. On the Keyboard page select a Keyboard mapping scheme.
> 3. In the Show commands containing text box, type a command-related
>    keyword to locate the command you want in the list box. For example,
>    if you want to create a shortcut that opens a new solution, you might
>    type "solution" in this text box.
> 4. In the scrolling list box, select the command you want the shortcut
>    to execute.
> 5. On the Use new shortcut in drop-down list, select the environment
>    in which you want to use the shortcut. Choose Global if you want the
>    shortcut to work in all contexts.
> 6. Place your cursor in the Press shortcut key(s) text box and then
>    press and hold a non-text key or combination of non-text keys (Alt,
>    Ctrl, or Shift, for example) and type the text key of your choice.
> 7. Choose Assign.

Or of course, you could add a build event that will execute the file on
the project building.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to trigger on save no matter how the save happens in VS2012, this seems pretty far from that.  Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: @AaronStainback Sorry, I'm not sure if that is possible without an extension/plugin of some sort.